# Import chat history from Skype in Windows to Skype in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, skype

I have a backup of my skype history from Windows using this guide
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA413/how-do-i-back-up-my-configuration-and-instant-message-history

and now I want to use that one in the skype that I have installed on Ubuntu 13.04. Is that possible? If yes then how do I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Skype doesn't offer that capability.  You would have to use 3rd party software to accomplish this.  Probably using an application like Skyperious would accomplish the task, though I would suggest a backup of both main.db files before attempting such a merge.

Skyperious : http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/

Answer (score 0):

Actually Skype stores the messages in `sqlite` format. You can try to use any sqlite browser to access the messages from `main.db` file.